# How to display dynamic html based on generic object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have created a class that can contain several instances of an object, all of the data is stored in the session. I won't know how many instances until run-time. What is the best approach for displaying this dynamic data. Im using aspx with code behind, so I assume it needs to happen in the load sub.

In case it helps, heres the class, its in VB but answers in c# are fine:

```
Imports System.Web.HttpContext

Public Class Student

    Public Property SchoolId As Integer
    Public Property Grade As Integer
    Public Property StudentName As String


    Public Sub AttachToSession(StudentToBeAdded As Student)

        Dim StudentList As New List(Of Student)

        If (Current.Session("student") Is Nothing) Then

            StudentList.Add(StudentToBeAdded)
            Current.Session("student") = StudentList

        Else

            StudentList = Current.Session("student")
            StudentList.Add(StudentToBeAdded)
            Current.Session("student") = StudentList

        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This question is extremely vague. Do you have a more specific question? Maybe you could show use what you've tried, or what result you are looking for?

Comment: sorry, I dont need the actual html, just a way to show dynamic data. Like i would normally just use a label or textbox and runat at server, but those controls dont map to my data structure. I was thinking of 2 possible ways - a label that contains an html string or somehow a custom control. Im not too advance in .net so Im not sure really

Comment: This would be helpful information in your question. You should consider editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or, if you want a custom look and feel, you could try something like this (in your aspx page):

```asp
<% For Each l_student As Student In CType( Session( "student" ), List(Of Student) ) %>
    <div>
        <p>Name: <%= l_student.StudentName %></p>
        <p>Grade: <%= l_student.Grade %></p>
    </div>
<% Next %>
```

This would create one 'div' element for each item in your student collection.

See: [Introduction to ASP.NET inline expressions in the .NET Framework](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112?wa=wsignin1.0)

You might be better off creating a shared property in your student class though:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly Property Students As List(Of Student)
    Get
        Dim l_studentList As List(Of Student) = TryCast( Current.Session("student"), List(Of Student) )
        If l_studentList Is Nothing Then
            l_studentList = New List(Of Student)
            Current.Session("student") = l_studentList
        End If

        Return l_studentList
    End Get
End Property
```

Then your aspx would be:

```
<% For Each l_student As Student In Student.Students %>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) control to display the students information

Markup

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
</asp:GridView>
```

In your code

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        GridView1.DataSource = CType(Session("student"), List(Of Student))
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. The other answer was a bit closer to what Im trying to accomplish